# PHP - Query works locally but not on server

Tags: php, sql, subquery

I am using the following query to get information about a student, a goal they have set, what standard it connects with, and what their current grade is for that standard.

There can be more than one grade per standard and I want the most recent one so I added a subquery to get the most recent date.

The code works well when I test it in XAMPP but does not load on my server. The databases are identical and I am not sure what else could be the problem.

```
SELECT users.firstName, goals.goalgrade, 
standards.standard, goals.why, grades.grade                                 
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN goals ON goals.userid = users.id
    LEFT JOIN standards ON standards.id = goals.mid
    LEFT JOIN grades ON grades.testId = standards.standard
        AND grades.userId = users.id
        AND grades.date = (SELECT date FROM grades ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE users.teacherId = :teacherId
AND users.block = :block
ORDER BY $sortall
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is bound to be something different. What have you investigated? Are you able to get MySQL connection? Do you have different versions of PHP or MySQL?  Do you have different PHP extension configurations (i.e PDO or mysqli)?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting, all my other queries work fine. I am not getting an error, the query just returns empty. The exact code runs fine locally. Same version of PHP and MySQL. As to extensions, all my queries are PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, figured I would share. The subquery with XAMPP was fine with date being by itself but the server needed me to add the table name I changed:

```
   grades.date = (SELECT date FROM grades ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

To:

```
AND grades.date = (SELECT grades.date FROM grades ORDER BY grades.date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

My server says it is running MySQL 5.0 while XAMPP is running MySQL 5.1.44. Not sure if this would make a difference but it worked. Cheers